# How to get user selected value from a printed menu using python?

Tags: python, linux

I have a printed menu with multiple options:

```
choice = input("Which task do you want to perform?:
        1. Task a
        2. Task b
        3. Task c 
Enter your choice: ")
```

Once the user makes a choice, I want to print:

```
verify = input("Proceed with Task a? [(Y)es/(N)o]":)
```

How do I get the value as the user selects a number without using if statements?

Example: User chooses 1 , how do I print "Task a" without using if statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you would object to using a module, but have you considered using PyInputPlus?

This is a module that handles this kind of thing; in particular I think the inputMenu() function would work very well for your case.

```
import pyinputplus as pyip
choice = pyip.inputMenu(['Task A', 'Task B', 'Task C'], numbered = True)

Output:

Please select one of the following:
 1. Task A
 2. Task B
 3. Task C

print(choice)
```

This helps take care of the if statements you would otherwise need, and you can simply print out the choice variable afterward.

Answer (score 0):

one way you can convert the string input into an int is like:

```
choice = int(input("Which task do you want to perform?:\n1. Task a \n2. Task b 
\n3. Task c \nEnter your choice: "))
```